# Create webpart saving its data on leaving article page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, save

I have one custom article page layout which has a multiple lookup field called Tags refered to Tag list. In this layout, I put a webpart which do the task edit Tags for me. When I create a page from the layout and edit it, the webpart let me to add/remove tags easilly. How can I save data in the webpart when user press on link to call out-of-box function to save the page.
Any help will be appreciated.